# iPhone : UITableViewCell: cell carry background color strip

Tags: iphone, ios-simulator

When i used

```
self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage: 
                                     [UIImage imageNamed:@"image_name.png"]];
```

the cell carry bottom part of image and it looks like strip on view

Comment: Hey. Could you be a bit more descriptive in your problem? What do you need help with?

Comment: when add background image as i told earlier, cell carry the bottom part of background image hence looks like background color broken and cell overlap on the screen
thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use the following method to set cell height exactly the same as your image's height:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

Also you might want to remove separators depending on how your image looks using the following code:

```
MyTableName.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone;
```

Comment: thanks for reply but it not working properly. cell carry the bottom part of background image hence looks like background color broken and cell overlap on the screen

Comment: Please provide the background image that you're using and a screenshot of your table view from the app, so I could check what kind of problem you're having